# PHP mysqli can't fetch data

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Hy,

I have a strange problem. This is the code:

First, I get the parameters and connect to the base.

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $id=$_GET['id']; // if I echo this, it outputs 0
    $category=$_GET['category'];// if I echo this, it outputs 'category1'
    $name=$_GET['name'];
 ?>
```

And now I went to fetch the data from the db:

```
<?php
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT modelID,modelName,modelLogo FROM model,maker WHERE model.makerID=maker.makerID AND model.makerID='.$id.' AND model.modelCategory='.$category.' ORDER BY modelName")) { 

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($modelID, $modelName,$modelLogo);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<a href="edit_model.php?id='.$modelID.'"><div class="box"><img src="'.$modelLogo.'" /><p>'.$modelName.'</p></div></a>';
    }

    $stmt->close();

    }

    else {
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
     }
?>
```

And this **won't** output nothing. **But when i run the sql query in myPhpAdmin, it returns the values.**

Query:

```
SELECT modelID,modelName,modelLogo 
FROM model,maker 
WHERE model.makerID=maker.makerID 
AND model.makerID='0' 
AND model.modelCategory='category1' 
ORDER BY modelName
```

Output: 0 // name // path

I put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` but it doesn't return any error. Also, I tried to put this code after the `$stmt->bind_result($modelID, $modelName,$modelLogo);` and this is the result:

`var_dumb($modelID);die();` it returned '0'.

`var_dumb($modelName);die();` it returned 'NULL'.

`var_dumb($modelLogo);die();` it returned 'NULL'

I can't figure out what's going on so any help is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your query in the PHP is bogus, change this:

```
... AND model.modelCategory='.$category.' ...
```

To this:

```
... AND model.modelCategory='$category' ...
```

Or better yet, since you are already using prepared statements, use [parameter binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) so you don't have to worry about this kind of thing.

Comment: he uses " around the query string so he just has to remove the . around the variables and it should work

Answer (score 3):

You are not binding the parameters. Try this.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT modelID,modelName,modelLogo FROM model,maker 
    WHERE model.makerID=maker.makerID 
    AND model.makerID = ? AND model.modelCategory = ? 
    ORDER BY modelName")) {
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $id, $category);
//rest of the code intact
```

Comment: Good to know this for the future. +1

Comment: The whole point of using prepared statements is to sanitize the inputs, and that happens with bind_param automatically. It will save you a lot of trouble in the future. :)

Comment: To tell the truth, I thought that binding the parameters is only used for DML (Data Manipulation Language) querys (INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements). I quess I thought wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sean Bright answered your question, but I'd prefer this one:

```
"SELECT 
  modelID, modelName, modelLogo 
FROM 
  model, maker 
WHERE 
  model.makerID=maker.makerID AND model.makerID='{$id}' 
AND 
  model.modelCategory='{$category}' 
ORDER BY modelName"
```

Just because such code editors as Notepad++ hightlight variables in strings making it easy to read.